# How to determine the outermost lines in a group of parallel lines?

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry, vector-graphics, lines

In a group of parallel lines, how can I determine which are the outermost lines? The lines can be in any angle of rotation.

Illustration:

`----` <- outermost
`----`
`----`
`----` <- outermost

Comment: What information do you have?  What have you tried?

Comment: I know the coordinates for all the lines.

Answer (score 6):

Put them in [general form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#General_form), then select the ones with the most extreme constant terms.

Comment: And for extra points, realize that for a set of parallel lines, the variable coefficients will be constant, but the constant term will vary. *runs*